# How to fix permissions error when installing Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I have Ruby 2.2.6 and Rails 5.0 installed succesfully, however I don't seem to be able to install gems. Here's the error I get:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1-x86-    mingw32/lib/nokogiri/2.3/nokogiri.so
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I searched for solutions but all the suggestions are for Unix commands.

I'm on Windows so I'm not sure how to enable permissions in order for this install to pass succesfully.

Any (ELI5 level) suggestions for me?

Comment: A *.so file is a Unix library file.  So something about your Ruby installation is messed up because its looking for Unix libraries, which of course it can't find on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1'
```

In your command line?
If you are still getting an error, post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [Nokogiri website](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#windows), you'll find special instructions for  installing it on Windows.

A number of Ruby libraries are called native libraries, meaning they're written in C for Unix, and so require Unix build tools to make.